# Powershell - adding two variables together receiving numbers from command line

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to receive input from the command line, such as adding two numbers, but I either return the literal variable number, the number 0, or invalid data.

With this code:

```
Param (
    [int]$a, 
    [int]$b
)
function add([int]$a,[int]$b)
{
    $var = $a+"$b"
    $a
    $b
    $var
    return $a + $b
}

add([int]$a,[int]$b)
```

This is the error I receive with this.

```
PS C:\> .\add.ps1 -a 5 -b 4
add : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'a'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32".
At C:\add.ps1:15 char:4
+ add <<<< ([int]$a,[int]$b)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [add], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,add
```

And then with

```
Param (
    [int]$a, 
    [int]$b
)
function add([int]$a,[int]$b)
{
    $var = $a+"$b"
    $a
    $b
    $var
    return $a + $b
}

add
```

It returns nothing but 0's. Then when I use this code:

```
Param (
    [int]$a, 
    [int]$b
)
function add($a,$b)
{
    $var = $a+"$b"
    $a
    $b
    $var
    return $a + $b
}

add($a,$b)
```

It just returns what I give as a command line argument. I am calling this program like this:

`.\add.ps1 -a 5 -b 4`

There's gotta be something I'm not doing correctly with Powershell. However, I'm not sure what terms, or how I should word my search because I get how to concatenate the variables, or just add plain integers, but not two variables with integers passed from the command line, in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function(argument1, argument2)` is not the correct syntax for calling for calling powershell functions. The correct syntax for calling a PowerShell function without the parameter names is `function argument1 argument2`.

What you're doing with

```
add([int]$a,[int]$b)
```

is supplying the **add** function with a single array argument—and that array is the object that cannot be converted to Int32 that's mentioned in the error message. In other words, you're providing the array `([int]$a,[int]$b)` as the value of the **add** function's **$a** parameter, and not supplying a value for the **add** function's **$b** parameter.*

Also, PowerShell is a dynamically typed language; there's no need to cast the arguments **$a** and **$b** as **[int]** in your function call, especially since you already cast them in the **param** list. Change the last line to this:

```
add $a $b
```

If for some reason you do want to cast the arguments to the function call, you can do it by evaluating each casting independently as an expression:

```
add ([int]$a) ([int]$b)
```

---

* To illustrate this, change the **add** function to:

```
function add($a, $b)
{
  "`nValue of parameter A:"
  $a
  "`nType of parameter A:"
  $a.GetType()
  "`nValue of parameter B:"
  $b
  "`nType of parameter B:"
  $b.GetType()
}
```

When you call it with

```
add([int]$a,[int]$b)
```

you get the following results, indicating that **A** is an array of two integers, and **B** is not defined:

```
Value of parameter A:
4
5

Type of parameter A:

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

Value of parameter B:

Type of parameter B:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Data Files\scratch\so\soscratch\add.ps1:15 char:3
+   $b.GetType()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to not re-use the variable names, since that can get confusing. I changed the variables in the function to `$c` and `$d` instead. Then call the function just like you called the script and it works just fine...

```
Param (
    [int]$a, 
    [int]$b
)
function add([int]$c,[int]$d)
{
    $var = $c+$d
    $c
    $d
    $var
    return $d + $c
}

add -c $a -d $b

PS C:\test> .\add.ps1 -a 5 -b 4
5
4
9
9
```

Comment: Both of these answers from TheMadTechnician and Adi Inbar are correct. Thank you guys.